# Calendar alert in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to set up an alert or reminder that will let me know one week in advance when a particular person on my calendar is going on vacation.  Is this possible and if so, could someone help!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "someone on my calendar"?

Comment: Basically, I want an alert when a particular employee of mine is going on vacation.  I've updated the calendar with names on the days they are off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new outlook appointment 1 week before the other one in your calendar, set the time as 'free' and take 30 minutes for that appointment and set a reminder of 0 minutes.

That way, it'll be obvious to you, as you will see it in your calendar and it'll remind you and the time will be free for someone else still to book a meeting.

If you would have created the appointment when your colleagues are on vacation yourself already, you can type: `1 week` in the existing reminder where it says "10 minutes"

Comment: Yes, that could work.  What I really would like is for it to automatically do this when a certain person is going to be on vacation.  I'm sure Outlook probably can't do that though.

Comment: That's the second case: `If you would have created the appointment when your colleagues are on vacation yourself already, you can type: 1 week in the existing reminder where it says "10 minutes"`  If you force them to send it to you, ask them to set the reminder to 1 week instead of 10 minutes.  It can be automated by a program that would read all of your calendar appointments using `MAPI` but that would be an entire day of work instead of just posting an answer.  **:-)**